# Copy file from s3 bucket having multiple folder using manifest file

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have multiple folders in s3 bucket, and each folder contains 2000+ parquet file.

File names looks like

```
part-0001-c000.snappy.parquet
```

and in each folder file name is same but data in file is different,
and all files need to load to redshift.

I am trying to use manifest file like.

```
{
    "entries": [
        {"url":"s3://redshift-load-queue/folder1/*", "mandatory":true},
        {"url":"s3://redshift-load-queue/folder2/*", "mandatory":true},
        {"url":"s3://redshift-load-queue/folder3/*", "mandatory":true},
        {"url":"s3://redshift-load-queue/folder4/*", "mandatory":true}
    ]
}
```

The code I am using to load the parquet file from s3 bucket is:

```
copy dimproduct -- target table
  from 's3://redshift-load-queue/manifest.txt' -- source path
  iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::XXXX' 
  region 'us-west-2'
  FORMAT AS PARQUET
  delimiter ','
```

but it seems it is not able to read all files from all folders.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the full file name in the manifest. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-files-using-manifest.html

> "The URL in the manifest must specify the bucket name and full object
> path for the file, not just a prefix."

Comment: what if there are 20k files . so do I need to provide full name of all 20k files in the Manifest?

Comment: Is there any better way to handle it. kindly share your expert knowledge.

Comment: If you want to specify '"mandatory":true' and ensure that all files are used in the COPY there is no other way than specifying all files individually.  If it was me I'd write a scripts to find all the files in the bucket that match your criteria and output the manifest file.  Even better would be to log the files from the sourcing process and generate the manifest along side the data files.